# How do I fix a corrupted build manager in vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# project in vs2010 that has several build options (Debug, Release, Debug x86, Debug I Just Got A New Hat, etc), because some people have gone a bit overboard in adding projects.

I want to revert all of that to just the four basic build types:

1. debug x86
2. release x86
3. debug x64
4. release x64

I remove a project, save the sln with that project apparently no longer in the solution, and then add it back, but apparently the settings for the project have been saved.  Is there any way to remove these extraneous projects entirely from the build manager and start from scratch short of creating a new SLN file?

The impetus for fixing this problem is that one of the projects in the solution won't allow for an x64 build to be made.  If I try to create an x64 build for that project, the build manager states that the x64 build already exists, even when though clearly does not.  The build manager isn't allowing me to remove build modes, just add them, but then it doesn't let me add the x64, which is what I'm needing.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way is to manually edit the .proj files in notepad, removing all the

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'NewHat|x64' ">...</PropertyGroup>
```

elements for each configuration. Then finally remove the unwanted solution configurations by again editing the .sln file in notepad. They are easy to spot.
Once removed, you should be able to open up the solution in VS and set things right in the configuration manager

The alternatives are to use a macro or VS EnvDTE classes to automate the process but that's perhaps the sledgehammer for a nut.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I don't recommend doing this but you may need to take Notepad or your favourite XML editor and change the contents of your csproj file.  The reason I don't like to recommend this approach is that if you get the editing wrong you can end up with a broken project.

Obviously you should back everything up before you start so you can at least get back to your current state if everything goes pear shaped.

Ideally you can dig into your Source Code Control system and get a copy of the csproj file from back when it wasn't broken and use that as a rough guide to what a well formed csproj file for your project looks like.

You can also create a completely new C# project using the same template as your project and use that project's csproj file as another guide to what things should look like.

If you're lucky your csproj file will contain a number of PropertyGroup items, some of which will have a condition identifying the particular build combination the group applies to.  For example...

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If you delete the groups for configurations you no longer want and delete any that seem to apply to x64 you may find that the build manager will let you add an x64 configuration.